# Assign memory for individual worker in storm

Tags: java, configuration, apache-storm, topology

I need to assign different values of memory for each new worker. So I tried changing memory for each bolt and spout. I am currently using a custom scheduler also. Here is my approach to the problem.

MY CODE:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout", new EmailSpout(), 1).addConfiguration("node", "zoo1").setMemoryLoad(512.0);
builder.setBolt("increment1", new IncrementBolt(), PARALLELISM).shuffleGrouping("spout").addConfiguration("node", "zoo2").setMemoryLoad(2048.0);
builder.setBolt("increment2", new IncrementBolt(), PARALLELISM).shuffleGrouping("increment1").addConfiguration("node", "zoo3").setMemoryLoad(2048.0);
builder.setBolt("increment3", new IncrementBolt(), PARALLELISM).shuffleGrouping("increment2").addConfiguration("node", "zoo4").setMemoryLoad(2048.0);
builder.setBolt("output", new OutputBolt(), 1).globalGrouping("increment2").addConfiguration("node", "zoo1").setMemoryLoad(512.0);
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(false);
conf.setNumWorkers(4);
StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar("Microbenchmark", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

MY STORM.YAML:

```
 storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "zoo1"
 storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
 nimbus.seeds: ["zoo1"]
 storm.local.dir: "/home/ubuntu/eranga/storm-data"
 supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
     - 6704
 storm.scheduler: "org.apache.storm.scheduler.NodeBasedCustomScheduler"
 supervisor.scheduler.meta:
     node: "zoo4"
 worker.profiler.enabled: true
 worker.profiler.childopts: "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"
 worker.profiler.command: "flight.bash"
 worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 1
 worker.childopts: "-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser -Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"
```

When I submit the topology I get the following error.

ERROR:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topology will not be able to be successfully scheduled: Config TOPOLOGY_WORKER_MAX_HEAP_SIZE_MB=768.0 < 2048.0 (Largest memory requirement of a component in the topology). Perhaps set TOPOLOGY_WORKER_MAX_HEAP_SIZE_MB to a larger amount
>
> at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.validateTopologyWorkerMaxHeapSizeMBConfigs(StormSubmitter.java:496)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.

```
import org.apache.storm.Config;

public class TopologyExecuter{
   for(List<StormTopology> StormTopologyObject : StormTopologyObjects ){
       Config topologyConf = new Config();
       topologyConf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS,"-Xmx512m -Xms256m");
       StormSubmitter.submitTopology("topology name", topologyConf, StormTopologyObject);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following the advice from the error message?

> Perhaps set TOPOLOGY_WORKER_MAX_HEAP_SIZE_MB to a larger amount

Try adding this to storm.yaml:

```
topology.worker.max.heap.size.mb=2048.0
```